# How to add two records with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, record

I need help on a problem I have. I have a list with several fields including contract, installment and amount.

I need to create a new list based on these fields, including all the others, of course.

So, for every contract with two installments, I need to sum the amounts into the first installment, while maintaining the second one.

You have an example below.

Is this possible?

```
...contract    instalment    amount ...
...1           1             100    ... 
...1           2             1000   ...
...2           1             100    ...
...3           1             1000   ...
...4           1             200    ...
...4           2             100    ...
...5           1             1000   ...

...contract    instalment    amount ...
...1           1             1100   ... 
...1           2             1000   ...
...2           1             100    ...
...3           1             1000   ...
...4           1             300    ...
...4           2             100    ...
...5           1             1000   ...
```

Comment: why do u want to retain other value? what happens if there are more than 2 records with same contractid?

Comment: btw short answer: Peform `GroupBy` on contract id with `amount` getting aggregated. The for each item in list for 1st unique id, replace above with sum.

Comment: Ankush, if there are 2 records with same contractid, I have to add the amounts into first record while retaining the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
var result = from record in records
             group record by record.Contract into contractGroup
             let orderedGroup = contractGroup.OrderBy(r => r.Instalment).ToList()
             let aggregatedItem = new Record 
                                  {
                                      Contract = contractGroup.Key,
                                      Instalment = orderedGroup.First().Instalment,
                                      Amount = orderedGroup.Sum(r => r.Amount) 
                                  }
             from resultRecord in new[] { aggregatedItem }
                                        .Concat(orderedGroup.Skip(1))              
             select resultRecord;
```

Note that in your sample, you only handle cases where groups contain one or two items, but the above code will also work for three or more items in a group by aggregating the first item from all the others.

**EDIT**:

Since you want to *mutate* the first record in each group rather than create a new one, I would do:

```
foreach(var contractGroup in records.GroupBy(record => record.Contract))
{
     // Use Aggregate or a dedicated MinBy operator
     // if you don't want the sorting overhead.
     var aggregateItem = contractGroup.OrderBy(record => record.Instalment)
                                      .First();     

     aggregateItem.Amount = contractGroup.Sum(record => record.Amount);  
}

// Now use 'records' as before as the subsequent data-source.
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, but I need all the fields in Record. How can I get them without having to assign them all??

Comment: You're asking for help with *mutating* existing records rather than passing them through / creating new ones. LINQ isn't appropriate for mutating existing data; it's normally used to create *new* data / pass existing data through in a new form. If you don't want to create a copy-constructor, you should use plain old imperative loops to do the mutations.

Comment: Works just fine, tks a million.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result via simple LINQ below:

```
var output = input.GroupBy(record => record.Contract)
            .SelectMany(group =>
                {
                    group.First().Amount = group.Sum(r => r.Amount);
                    return group;
                })
            .ToList();
```